# Date Validation with Javascript, ".date":{rx:.........,target:'input'},

Tags: javascript, html, validation, date

This is what my code currently looks like:

```js
;(function($){
 $.fn.forms=function(o){
  return this.each(function(){
   var th=$(this)
    ,_=th.data('forms')||{
     errorCl:'error',
     emptyCl:'empty',
     invalidCl:'invalid',
     notRequiredCl:'notRequired',
     successCl:'success',
     successShow:'4000',
     mailHandlerURL:'bat/MailHandler.php',
     ownerEmail:'email@email.com',
     stripHTML:true,
     smtpMailServer:'localhost',
     targets:'input,textarea',
     controls:'a[data-type=reset],a[data-type=submit]',
     validate:true,
     rx:{
      ".name":{rx:/^[a-zA-Z'][a-zA-Z-' ]+[a-zA-Z']?$/,target:'input'},
      ".email":{rx:/^(("[\w-\s]+")|([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)|("[\w-\s]+")([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*))(@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$)|(@\[?((25[0-5]\.|2[0-4][0-9]\.|1[0-9]{2}\.|[0-9]{1,2}\.))((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1,2})\.){2}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1,2})\]?$)/i,target:'input'},
      ".phone":{rx:/^\+?(\d[\d\-\+\(\) ]{5,}\d$)/,target:'input'},
      ".date":{rx:/.{20}/,target:'input'},
      ".serve":{rx:/^\+?(\d[\d\-\+\(\) ]{1,}\d$)/,target:'input'},
      ".occasion":{rx:/^[a-zA-Z'][a-zA-Z-' ]+[a-zA-Z']?$/,target:'input'},
      ".flavour":{rx:/^[a-zA-Z'][a-zA-Z-' ]+[a-zA-Z']?$/,target:'input'},
      ".message":{rx:/.{20}/,target:'textarea'}
     },
```

All I would like to know is what I should do for:

```js
   ".date":{rx:/.{20}/,target:'input'},
   ".serve":{rx:/^\+?(\d[\d\-\+\(\) ]{1,}\d$)/,target:'input'},
   ".occasion":{rx:/^[a-zA-Z'][a-zA-Z-' ]+[a-zA-Z']?$/,target:'input'},
   ".flavour":{rx:/^[a-zA-Z'][a-zA-Z-' ]+[a-zA-Z']?$/,target:'input'},
```

what I mean is, what should the '/^+?(\d[\d-+() ]{1,}\d$)/', the stuff in the middle be and what are they for/do?

I am 100% new at JavaScript as I am used to PHP and HTML.
This is a website with will be used for my cake bakery.

I want the date to work with dd/mm/yyy
I want the serve to work with at least 1 number
I want the occasion to work with any text
and I want the flavour to work with any text

e.g.
Date: 08/12/2016
Server: 23
Occasion: Birthday
Flavour: Chocolate

Comment: Welcome to SO. The `'/^\+?(\d[\d-+() ]{1,}\d$)/'` is called Regular Expressions (RegEx), which are used to parse a text string or file. This particular one looks like it's matching (what looks to be) a phone number.

Comment: The regex for "dd/mm/yyyy" would be `'/^\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}$/'`.

Comment: thank you @philtune what would I do for the 'server', 'flavour' and 'occasion'? this is what I currently have:

Comment: ".serve":{rx:/.{0}/,target:'input'},

Comment: ".occasion":{rx:/^[a-zA-Z'][a-zA-Z-' ]+[a-zA-Z']?$/,target:'input'},

Comment: ".flavour":{rx:/^[a-zA-Z'][a-zA-Z-' ]+[a-zA-Z']?$/,target:'input'},

Comment: Well best to go look up some resources for RegEx... it would be a good education. But quickly looking, `.{20}` means any character 20 times, your `.occasion` and `.flavour` regex looks rather messed up... its just any combination of letters, spaces, and apostrophes that begin and end with the same... it doesn't make sense and could be simplified. But again, go look up some resources for "regular expressions" as it would be time well spent. I personally use http://www.regular-expressions.info/